# Oracle Pl/sql Select sum(var_col_nm) from var_table_nm;

Tags: oracle, plsql

Inside an anonymous block I want to executive the following oracle query:

```
Select sum(var_col_nm) from var_table_nm;
```

I'm getting error at this line as table name and column name are refering to a variable!

Is there in way out?

Code snippet:

```
Delare
v_col_nm varchar2(200);
v_table_nm varchar2(200);
Begin
   For j in (select col_nm1,col_nm2 from table) loop
         v_table_nm:=j.col_nm1;
         v_col_nm:=j.col_nm2;
         Select sumy(v_col_nm) from v_table_nm; --here I'm getting error.
       Other logic;
End Loop;
End;
```

Comment: Table name cannot be parametrized in static SQL query.

Comment: what's `sumy`, a mistype ..? and where's `into` which's missing in the line you get the error, after `sum(v_col_nm)`.

Comment: Thanks for your advise! I tried like: EXECUTE IMMIDIATE 'SELECT SUM('||v_col_nm||')into' || v_var|| 'from' || v_table_nm; still getting error as FROM KEYWORD NOT FOUND WHERE EXPECTED.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `execute immediate` for [dynamic SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97385_01/appdev.920/a96590/adg09dyn.htm):

```
 execute immediate 'Select sum(' 
 || v_col_nm || ') from '  || v_table_nm;
```

As @AlexPoole suggested you should probably add extra variable to select into the result

Comment: Use `||` for string concatenation in Oracle, not `+`. (You also need to select *into* something, but the OP was missing that part too...)

Comment: Thanks for your advise! I tried like: EXECUTE IMMIDIATE 'SELECT SUM('||v_col_nm||')into' || v_var|| 'from' || v_table_nm; still getting error as FROM KEYWORD NOT FOUND WHERE EXPECTED.

Comment: @Arnab you are missing spaces before and after from `' from '`. Same with into

Comment: Thanks for pointing out! I tried like: EXECUTE IMMIDIATE 'SELECT SUM('||v_col_nm||')into' || v_var|| ' from ' || v_table_nm; now getting error as MISSING EXPRESSION!

Comment: @Arnab same spacing with `' into '`